# Kubernetes Pod won't start - 1 node(s) had a volume affinity conflict

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a pod that won't start with a volume affinity conflict. This is a bare-metal cluster so it's unrelated to regions. The pod has 4 persistent volume claims which are all reporting bound so I'm assuming it's not one of those. There are 4 nodes, one of them is tainted so that the pod will not start on it, one of them is tainted specifically so that the pod WILL start on it. That's the only affinity I have set up to my knowledge. The message looks like this:

```
0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {XXXXXXX}, 
that the pod didn't tolerate, 1 node(s) had volume node 
affinity conflict, 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory.
```

This is what I would have expected apart from the volume affinity conflict. There are no other affinities set other than to point it at this node. I'm really not sure why it's doing this or where to even begin. The message isn't super helpful. It does NOT say which node or which volume there is a problem with. The one thing I don't really understand is how binding works. One of the PVC's is mapped to a PV on another node however it is reporting as bound so I'm not completely certain if that's the problem. I am using local-storage as the storage class. I'm wondering if that's the problem but I'm fairly new to Kubernetes and I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the Pod, the taints and tolerations, as well as the node affinity you've set up? 

You usually can't force a pod to start on a certain node only with taints and tolerations, but you probably meant nodeAffinity, which does make that possible

Answer (score 0):

You got 4 Nodes but none of them are available for scheduling due to a different set of conditions. Note that each Node can be affected by multiple issues and so the numbers can add up to more than what you have on total nodes. Let's try to address these issues one by one:

- `Insufficient memory`: Execute `kubectl describe node <node-name>` to check how much free memory is available there. Check the requests and limits of your pods. Note that Kubernetes will block the full amount of memory a pod requests regardless how much this pod uses.
- `Insufficient cpu`: Analogical as above.
- `node(s) had volume node affinity conflict`: Check out if the `nodeAffinity` of your PersistentVolume (`kubectl describe pv`) matches the node label (`kubectl get nodes`). Check if the `nodeSelector` in your pod also matches. Make sure you set up the `Affinity` and/or `AntiAffinity` rules correctly. More details on that can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).
- `node(s) had taint {XXXXXXX}, that the pod didn't tolerate`: You can use `kubectl describe node` to check taints and `kubectl taint nodes <node-name> <taint-name>-` in order to remove them. Check the [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) for more details.

Comment: I got a little further. I hadn't specified in the persistent volumes which PVC's they should bind to. Strangely, about 13 of the 16 PVC's seemed to bind dynamically to the PV's that fit their size. When I added the mapping in the PV's it got me further. However I've now happened on another issue. One PVC is shared between 2 pods and that's causing one of the pods to fail to start due to taints meaning those 2 pods can never be on the same node. As I'm using local-storage at this point I'm guessing this ain't going to work in this scenario and I would need to use something like NFS.